# Django, Postgresql raise OperationalError

Tags: python, django, exception, django-models, django-postgresql

I working in Ubuntu 12.04, Django 1.5.1 and Postgresql 9.1 and suddenly i get an error

```
Exception Type: OperationalError
Exception Value: FATAL:  cache lookup failed for access method 403
```

... what did that mean?

Comment: Is your `Postgresql server` up and running?

Comment: thanks for response... but my problems solved by reinstalling ubuntu and postgres.